# Strict local minimiser

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $\Omega$ be a convex subset of $R^n$ adm f is a real valued, twice differentiable function. Let $x^*$ to be a point in $\Omega$ and suppose that there exists $c \in R \, c >0$ s.t. for all feasible directions d $d\neq0$ at $x^*$ we have that $d^Tf'(x^*) \geq 0$ and $d^T f''(x^*)d \geq c||d||^2$. How to show that $x^*$ is a strict local minimizer of f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Taylor expansion
$$f(x^* + t \, d) = f(x^*) + f'(x^*) \, d + \frac{t^2}2 \, d^\top f''(x^*) \, d + o(\|t\,d\|^2).
$$
If $d$, $\|d\| \le 1$, is a feasible direction, you obtain for some $T > 0$, that for all $t \in [0,T]$ you have
$$
f(x^* + t \, d) \ge f(x^*) + \frac c4 \, \|t \, d\|^2.
$$
This shows that $x^*$ is a strict local minimizer.

Comment: Dear grew, I am happy if you could take a look on the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232885/stable-local-minimizers